# I am getting FileNotFound exception while reading the text file from Assets folder

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

```
public class intro extends AppCompatActivity {

    private StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intro);
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("assets/Introduction.txt")));

            // do reading, usually loop until end of file reading
            String mLine;
            while ((mLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(mLine);
                text.append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error reading file!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //log the exception
                }
            }

            TextView output= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.intro);
            output.setText((CharSequence) text);

        }
    }
[This is my project explorer][1]}
```

I tried lot of paths for opening assets folder but it is showing filenotfound exception. Here I have created Introduction.txt file in Assets folder and written some content on it. But I can't open it by giving path or file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `assets/` from `"assets/Introduction.txt"`. The path supplied to `open()` is the relative path *within* your `assets/`.

Comment: I removed But even it is not working...It says FileNotFound

Comment: @Chitrapandi: Then you do not have `Introduction.txt` in the root directory of your assets (e.g., `src/main/assets/` within your module).

Comment: No, I am having see my project Explorer here--->https://i.stack.imgur.com/OklGw.png

Comment: @Chitrapandi: You have a file named `Introduction`, not `Introduction.txt`.

Comment: ohh... I thought that it will take it as text file extension(.txt)... It's worked thank you @CommonsWare